# Android :Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter, abstract-class

Getting the error when i am trying to perform on onClickEventOccure in adapter class
 **android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application**

Here the logcat:

```
07-27 14:53:46.249 30907-30907/com.sgrip E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.sgrip, PID: 30907
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:583)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:282)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
    at com.sgrip.activities.Pending_Request$2.onClickEventOccure(Pending_Request.java:160)
    at com.sgrip.adapter.AdapterNotification$3.onClick(AdapterNotification.java:67)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19884)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

i am trying to call datepicker dialog on recycleview's listitem but getting this error.

please help me out from this stuck very bad on this....
thanks in advance.. ...

Comment: The issue is with the `Dialog`, but you've not shown that code.

Comment: thank you i got it  instead of this 
DialogUtil.showProgress(Pending_Request.this);  I am trying DialogUtil.showProgress(getApplicationContext());

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Did you get it fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `Activity.this` instead of `getApplicationContext()`